# I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with my code, my IDE gives me an error

Tags: c++, string, pointers, character

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with my code, I keep getting an error concerning the 'c' in line 11. I know my syntax is correct, and I'm pretty sure my logic is correct, so what's the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int counter(char *, char);
int main()
{
   const int size = 51;
   char input[size];
   char consonants = { 'b''c''d''f''g''h''j''k''l''m''n''p''q''r''s''t''v''w''x''y''z'};
   cout << "Enter your letters." << endl;
   cin.getline(input, consonants);
   cout << consonants << "appears";
   cout << counter(input, consonants) << "times" << endl;
}

int counter(char *strPtr, char ch)
{
   int times = 0;
   while (*strPtr != '\0')
   {
      if (*strPtr == ch)
        times++;
      strPtr++;
   }
   return times;
}
```

Comment: *"I know my syntax is correct"* - Sure about that?

Comment: Whenever you ask a programming question, always include the ***exact*** error messages. Compiler writers put a lot of effort into generating useful diagnostics. Don't let their effort go to waste!

Comment: Jonathon's got a great point there... not just because it helps people here diagnose your problem, also because answers can explain how the compiler error was trying to explain the problem to you - so you'll recognise it yourself in future and get a better handle on the terminology and perspective of all compiler messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'b''c''d''f'`... is not valid C++.  Try...

```
const char consonants[] = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', ... };
```

...which - BTW - you can simplify to just:

```
const char consonants[] = "bcdf...";
```

(You will have other issues after that... for example the `cin.getline()` overloads you could call are:

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

...and for neither of those is `cin.getline(input, consonants);` a valid invocation, as `consonants` is not a `streamsize` value.

To be honest, I can't even begin to imagine how you expect this code to work overall.  If you want to use `counter` to report on the frequency of each of the consonants, you need e.g. a `for` loop over those consonants in `main()`.)

Answer (score 0):

Should it be...

```
char consonants = { 'b\'c'};
```

but if you want to create an array of char, it should be

```
char consonants[]  = {'b','c'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, your call of:

```
out << counter(input, consonants) << "times" << endl;
```

is passing consonants to a function expecting the second argument of a single character.  This is an address to an array you are passing - not a single element.